# Ionic 3 - In app purchase using Inapppurchase2 plugin giving no response

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, in-app-purchase, cordova-plugins

I have installed the plugin implemented the code.. Uploaded the signed apk as Internal tester but when I click the purchase button nothing happens.. Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NewTransactionPage } from '../instamojo/new_transaction';
import { IonicPage, Platform, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppPurchase2, IAPProduct } from '@ionic-native/in-app-purchase-2/ngx';



@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-pay',
templateUrl: 'pay.html',
})

export class PayPage {

public product: any = {
name: 'Upgrade to Pro',
appleProductId: 'android.test.purchased',
googleProductId: 'ultimate'
  };

constructor(
public navCtrl: NavController, 
public navParams: NavParams,
public platform: Platform,
public store: InAppPurchase2
) {
  platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.configurePurchasing();
  });

}

configurePurchasing() {
if (!this.platform.is('cordova')) { return; }
let productId;
try {
  if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
    productId = this.product.appleProductId;
  } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
    productId = this.product.googleProductId;
  }

  // Register Product
  // Set Debug High
  this.store.verbosity = this.store.DEBUG;

  // Register the product with the store
  this.store.register({
    id: productId,
    alias: productId,
    type: this.store.NON_CONSUMABLE
  });

  this.registerHandlers(productId);

  InAppPurchase2.getPlugin().ready().then((status) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.store.get(productId)));
    console.log('Store is Ready: ' + JSON.stringify(status));
    console.log('Products: ' + JSON.stringify(this.store.products));

  });

  // Errors On The Specific Product
  this.store.when(productId).error( (error) => {
    alert('An Error Occured' + JSON.stringify(error));
  });
  // Refresh Always
  console.log('Refresh Store');
  this.store.refresh();
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Error On Store Issues' + JSON.stringify(err));
}
 }

 registerHandlers(productId) {
// Handlers
this.store.when(productId).approved( (product: IAPProduct) => {
  // Purchase was approved
  product.finish();
});

this.store.when(productId).registered( (product: IAPProduct) => {
  console.log('Registered: ' + JSON.stringify(product));
});

this.store.when(productId).updated( (product: IAPProduct) => {
  console.log('Loaded' + JSON.stringify(product));
});

this.store.when(productId).cancelled( (product) => {
  alert('Purchase was Cancelled');
});

// Overall Store Error
this.store.error( (err) => {
  alert('Store Error ' + JSON.stringify(err));
});
}

async purchase() {
/* Only configuring purchase when you want to buy, because when you configure a purchase
It prompts the user to input their apple id info on config which is annoying */
if (!this.platform.is('cordova')) { return };

let productId;

if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
  productId = this.product.appleProductId;
} else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
  productId = this.product.googleProductId;
}

console.log('Products: ' + JSON.stringify(this.store.products));
console.log('Ordering From Store: ' + productId);
try {
  let product = this.store.get(productId);
  console.log('Product Info: ' + JSON.stringify(product));
  let order = this.store.order(productId);
  alert('Finished Purchase');
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Error Ordering ' + JSON.stringify(err));
}
}

backHomePage() {
this.navCtrl.pop();
}

}
```

I have tried building the app without --prod but still its not working. I am calling the purchase() function but nothing happens

Comment: Did you find anything? I am having exact same issue.

Comment: Yes. Being an idiot, I was using ionic 4 in-app purchase NPM package on ionic 3 project

Comment: I am using ionic 4 and using ionic 4 npm package but still I am having exact same issue.

Comment: Well.. I have to see your code to understand the problem

Comment: Can you take a look at my code? Can you share some contact?